# Why doesn't the value in the stack update eventough its a reference

Tags: c++

I have the following struct and class definition that I'm having an issue with:

```
struct customer{
    string fullname;
    double payment;
};

class Stack{
private:
    int top;
    customer stack[10];
    bool full;
    double sum;
public:
    Stack(){ 
        top=0; 
        full=false;
        double sum=0.0;
    }

    bool isFull(){
        return full;
    }

    void push(customer &c){
        if(!full)
            stack[top++]=c;
        else
            cout << "Stack full!" << endl;
    }

    void pop(){
        if(top>0){
            sum+=stack[--top].payment;
            cout << "Cash status: $" << sum << endl;
        }
        else
            cout << "Stack empty!" << endl;
    }
};
```

I run the following code in main:

```
int main(){
    customer c1 = {"Herman", 2.0};
    customer c2 = {"Nisse", 3.0};
    Stack stack = Stack();
    stack.push(c1);
    stack.push(c2);
    c2.payment=10.0;
    cout << c2.payment << endl;
    stack.pop();
    stack.pop();
    return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't the sum add up to 12? I specified push constructor to be: `void push(customer &c)`. The output from the code is:

```
10
Cash status: $3
Cash status: $5
```

Should the value in the stack be updated when I update c2.payment to 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the argument by reference, but your assignment below is copying the referenced object into the stack.

> stack[top++]=c;

This is using an implicitly generated assignment operator, which copies each of the members of the customer class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the value of c2 before adding it to the stack.